# Proof in complex variable

Tags: complex-analysis

I've been trying to do a proof for this and I can't get anywhere:

If $f:U\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a complex function, such that for every closed $C^1$ path $\int_\gamma f(z)dz=0$, then $f$ is analytic.

I tried to proof that $f$ has to verify Cauchy-Riemann equations by deriving or trying to relate that zero to derivatives, but I didn't get anywhere.

Comment: This is a standard result called [Morera's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morera%27s_theorem). What tools have you developed, and what results do you know?

Comment: Google "Morera's Theorem"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sketch of a proof, with the details left for you to fill in: Fix a $z_0 \in U$ and define

$$F(z) = \int_{\gamma} f(z) dz$$

where $\gamma$ is any path from $z_0$ to $z$. Convince yourself that $F$ is well-defined, analytic, and that $F' = f$. Now conclude.

Comment: Thank you, I read the wikipedia's proof. I don't understand, though, that if $F'=f$ how can we conclude that $f$ is holomorphic, because a derivable function doesn't necessarilly have a derivable derivative, does it?

Comment: @MyUserIsThis A holomorphic function has derivatives of *all* orders; in particular, $F'' = f'$, and so on.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I was seeing the definition and it only said differentiable in every point. Thank you again for your help